# How can I prevent my computer from accessing thousands of websites?

Tags: python, web, firefox, hosts-file, opendns

I'd like to block access to domains from my computer.

This is what I tried

1. I tried to use the domain filter in my router, but it applies only the HTTP websites. Any website that relies on HTTPS gets by the filter, even if the filter is looking for a domain with the same name, and that makes this approach not work.
2. I put the list of websites in my `/etc/hosts` file. It's thousands of websites and my `/etc/hosts` file was at 200MB. I had to delete this because my internet speed slowed down to a standstill. My internet wouldn't work at all.

I'm reading about LittleSnitch (which seems hard to configure with thousands of sites) and OpenDNS.

I don't want to set up a white list because I may want to access other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PiHole will do this - you can blacklist sites.

[www.pihole.org](http://www.pihole.org)

Comment: Is having a pihole like having opendns but with my custom list of websites?

Comment: Can I use open dns and pi hole at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can - I do it myself!

Here are a few links that I found useful:

https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/a6l9va/pivpn_with_pihole/

and

https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/pihole-with-openvpn-the-easy-way-use-pivpn/7912